# SQLAlchemy Migrate - Can I add (or modify) a column to a certain position of an existing table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I want to add a column to a certain position of an existing table or move one of the columns.
But I can't find any method in Sqlalchemy-migrate.

I want to know methods equivalent following MySQL queries in sqlalchemy-migrate

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD column_name2 INT AFTER column_name1
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD column_name2 INT FIRST
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN column_name2 INT AFTER column_name1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps:

1. create temp table,
2. copy records in temp table
3. rename temp to original table.

During ALTER operation flow as well, these operation will be executed internally.